# Calculating the min and max timing for going to bed

Tags: python, pandas

I am a novice in using python and pandas so please pardon my ignorance.

I am tracking my sleep habits using a watch to see what time I usually go to bed. In this hypothetical example, I have this data (just an excerpt of the overall data I have):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["16/10/2022", "17/10/2022", "18/10/2022", "19/10/2022"],
        "Time": ["2:15:00 AM", "11:30:00 PM", "12:20:00 AM", "1:15:00 AM"],
    }
)
```

I tried to find the minimum time (i.e.earliest time I go to bed) and the maximum time (the latest I went to bed) using the describe function after converting them to datetime objects.

```
df["Date and Time"] = df["Date"] + " " + df["Time"]
df["Date and Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date and Time"])
```

However, the statistics given for the min and the max are given by pandas are as follows

|  | Date and Time |
| --- | --- |
| count | 4 |
| mean | 2022-10-17 18:50:00 |
| min | 2022-10-16 02:15:00 |
| 25% | 2022-10-17 12:11:15 |
| 50% | 2022-10-17 23:55:00 |
| 75% | 2022-10-18 06:33:45 |
| max | 2022-10-19 01:15:00 |

I would expect the output for the min to be 11:30 PM, rather than at 2:15:00 AM, and the max to be 2:15:00am, rather than 1:15:00 AM.

If I do not join the "Time" and "Date" column as shown:

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"])
df.describe(datetime_is_numeric=True)
```

Then the output is thus:

|  | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| count | 4 | 4 |
| mean | 2022-10-17 12:00:00 | 2022-10-20 06:50:00 |
| min | 2022-10-16 00:00:00 | 2022-10-20 00:20:00 |
| 25% | 2022-10-16 18:00:00 | 2022-10-20 01:01:15 |
| 50% | 2022-10-17 12:00:00 | 2022-10-20 01:45:00 |
| 75% | 2022-10-18 06:00:00 | 2022-10-20 07:33:45 |
| max | 2022-10-19 00:00:00 | 2022-10-20 23:30:00 |

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I would expect the output for the min to be 11:30 PM, rather than at 2:15:00 AM" **Why**? I think a day starts at midnight, therefore 2:15 AM is near the beginning of a day, and 11:30 PM is near the end. Otherwise, what rule should we use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the problem (as far as I can see) comes from PM having to be considered earlier than AM, an obvious solution would be to swap these, get the min and max, then swap the results; here's my take on this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["16/10/2022", "17/10/2022", "18/10/2022", "19/10/2022"],
        "Time": ["2:15:00 AM", "11:30:00 PM", "12:20:00 AM", "1:15:00 AM"],
    }
)



# function that adds 12h to a datetime.time object
# (for the purpose of swapping PM and AM)

def time_swap(my_time):
    fake_date = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1, my_time.hour, my_time.minute, my_time.second)
    fake_date = fake_date + dt.timedelta(hours=12)
    return fake_date.time()



# Of course, the 2 following steps can be combined in one

# Converting Time to datetime.time values

Times = [pd.to_datetime(x).time() for x in df["Time"]]


# Swapping AM and PM

Times = [time_swap(x) for x in Times]



# Getting the extreme times

print(time_swap(min(Times)))
print(time_swap(max(Times)))
```

Of course, you lose the use of the describe method, and calculating the average would require another function. Another possible solution would be to swap "A" and "P" in the original string Times, analyze the data, then treat the results (swapping times again).

Comment: Your proposed solution seems to work for me. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you don't convert them as datetime objects, it works as you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["16/10/2022", "17/10/2022", "18/10/2022", "19/10/2022"],
                   "Time": ["2:15:00 AM", "11:30:00 PM", "12:20:00 AM", "1:15:00 AM"]})
```

```
>>> df.Time.min()
'11:30:00 PM'
>>> df.Time.max()
'2:15:00 AM'
>>> df[df.Time.min() == df.Time]
         Date         Time
1  17/10/2022  11:30:00 PM
>>> df[df.Time.max() == df.Time]
         Date        Time
0  16/10/2022  2:15:00 AM
```

Comment: It working is just a fluke: if you replace "11:30:00 PM" with "9:30:00 PM" for example, it will fail. Comparing strings won't do it; the original problem comes from ... PM having to be treated as earlier than ... AM .